# eigen: expression or function to set/return full column

Tags: c++, c++17, eigen, eigen3

I have several instances in my code, where I have a condition based on coefficients of 1xN arrays, and need to set whole columns of MxN arrays depending on these conditions. In my case, N is `Eigen::Dynamic` and M ranges from 2 to 4, but is a compile-time constant in each instance.

Here's a simple function illustrating what I mean, with `a` and `b` being the 1xN arrays which form the condition, `c` being a 2xN array with additional data, and `res` being an out-parameter, whose columns are always set as a whole:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>

using namespace Eigen;

template<Index nRows>
using ArrayNXd = Array<double, nRows, Dynamic>;

using Array1Xd = ArrayNXd<1>;
using Array2Xd = ArrayNXd<2>;
using Array3Xd = ArrayNXd<3>;

void asFunction(
    Array3Xd& res,
    const Array1Xd& a, const Array1Xd& b, const Array2Xd& c
){
    for (Index col{0}; col<a.cols(); ++col){
        if ( a[col] > b[col] )
            res.col(col) = Array3d{
                 a[col] + b[col],
                (a[col] + b[col]) * c(0, col),
                (a[col] - b[col]) * c(1, col)
            };
        else
            res.col(col) = Array3d{
                 a[col] - b[col],
                 a[col] + b[col],
                (a[col] + b[col]) * (a[col] - b[col])
            };
    }
}


int main(){
    Array1Xd a (3), b(3);
    Array2Xd c (2, 3);
    
    a << 1, 2, 3;
    b << 0, 1, 2;
    c <<
        0, 1, 2,
        1, 2, 3;

    Array3Xd res (3,3);
    
    asFunction(res, a, b, c);

    std::cout << "as function:\n" << res << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Functions similar to this are used in a performance cricital section* of my code, and I feel like I'm leaving performance on the table, because using loops with `Eigen` types is typically not the optimal solution.

*yes, I profiled it.

I wrote the same function as a `NullaryExpr`, but that was a bit slower. I guess that makes sense, given the additional evaluations of the condition(s) and the branching for each row:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>

using namespace Eigen;

template<Index nRows>
using ArrayNXd = Array<double, nRows, Dynamic>;

using Array1Xd = ArrayNXd<1>;
using Array2Xd = ArrayNXd<2>;
using Array3Xd = ArrayNXd<3>;

class MyFunctor
{
public:
    using Scalar = double;

    static constexpr Index
        RowsAtCompileTime { 3 },
        MaxRowsAtCompileTime { 3 },
        ColsAtCompileTime { Dynamic },
        MaxColsAtCompileTime { Dynamic };

    using DenseType = Array<
        Scalar  ,    RowsAtCompileTime,    ColsAtCompileTime,
        ColMajor, MaxRowsAtCompileTime, MaxColsAtCompileTime
    >;

private:
    typename Array1Xd::Nested m_a;
    typename Array1Xd::Nested m_b;
    typename Array2Xd::Nested m_c;

public:
    MyFunctor(
        const Array1Xd& a,
        const Array1Xd& b,
        const Array2Xd& c
    ) : m_a {a}, m_b {b}, m_c{c}
    {}

    bool cond(Index col) const {
        return m_a[col] > m_b[col];
    }

    Scalar func1(Index col) const {
        return m_a[col] + m_b[col];
    }

    Scalar func2(Index col) const {
        return m_a[col] - m_b[col];
    }

    Scalar func3(Index row, Index col) const {
        switch(row){
            case 0: return func1(col);
            case 1: return func1(col) * m_c(0, col);
            case 2: return func2(col) * m_c(1, col);
            default: __builtin_unreachable();
        }
    }

    Scalar func4(Index row, Index col) const {
        switch (row){
            case 0: return func2(col);
            case 1: return func1(col);
            case 2: return func1(col) / func2(col);
            default: __builtin_unreachable();
        }
    }

    Scalar operator() (Index row, Index col) const {
        if ( cond(col) )
            return func3(row, col);
        else
            return func4(row, col);
    }
};

using MyReturnType = Eigen::CwiseNullaryOp<
    MyFunctor, typename MyFunctor::DenseType
>;


MyReturnType asFunctor(
    const Array1Xd& a,
    const Array1Xd& b,
    const Array2Xd& c
){
    using DenseType = typename MyFunctor::DenseType;
    return DenseType::NullaryExpr(
        3, a.cols(),
        MyFunctor(a, b, c)
    );
}


int main(){
    Array1Xd a (3), b(3);
    Array2Xd c (2, 3);
    
    a << 1, 2, 3;
    b << 0, 1, 2;
    c <<
        0, 1, 2,
        1, 2, 3;

    std::cout << "as functor:\n" << asFunctor(a,b,c) << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

My question is: **Is there a more efficient way of implementing logic similar to the above** (evaluate scalar condition for each column of a matrix, return values for the whole column based on the condition) **using the `eigen` library?**

Note: using an expression would be slightly preferred, because I don't need to worry about memory allocation, out-parameters, etc., and the code can be written with scalars in mind, which makes it much more easily understandable.

Edit: Note2: I tried using `<Condition>.template replicate<nRows,1>().select(..., ...)` as well, but it was slower and harder to read.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Eigen's select method, but it only works for scalars, so you have to loop along one dimension.

```
const auto condition = a > b;
res.row(0) = condition.select(a + b /*true*/, a - b /*false*/);
res.row(1) = condition.select((a + b) * c.row(0), a + b);
res.row(2) = condition.select((a - b) * c.row(1), (a + b) * (a - b));
```

Note that you are probably faster if you transpose all your arrays. Then iteration goes column by column which vectorized much better since Eigen is column-major.

Comment: Thank you, but as I've written in "Note2" I've already tried `select`.
Also, transposing is not an option, because then components of variables would not be contiguous in memory. And 1xN arrays can still be column-major.

Comment: Btw, while `select` works on coefficients, you can use `replicate` on your condition to use it on whole columns. So e.g.
`res = condition.replicate(3,1).select(...,...)`, as I've written in my second note. Therefore, you can still let Eigen do the looping.

Answer (score 0):

so I only looked at this bit of code

```
    for (Index col{0}; col<a.cols(); ++col){
        if ( a[col] > b[col] )
            res.col(col) = Array3d{
                 a[col] + b[col],
                (a[col] + b[col]) * c(0, col),
                (a[col] - b[col]) * c(1, col)
            };
        else
            res.col(col) = Array3d{
                 a[col] - b[col],
                 a[col] + b[col],
                (a[col] + b[col]) * (a[col] - b[col])
            };
    }
```

I suspect, but cannot prove, that those a[col] and b[col] are getting accessed every single time you call them. You might want to try making short temporaries for the values that you reuse. For example:
so I only looked at this bit of code

```
    for (Index col{0}; col<a.cols(); ++col){
        auto acol=a[col];
        auto bcol=b[col];
        auto apb=acol+bcol;
        auto amb=acol-bcol;
        if ( acol > bcol )
            res.col(col) = Array3d{
                 apb,
                (apb) * c(0, col),
                (amb) * c(1, col)
            };
        else
            res.col(col) = Array3d{
                 amb,
                 apb,
                (apb) * (amb)
            };
    }
```

and yes I know this isn't exactly what you wanted. maybe it helps tho

Comment: It was really only a simplified example for my code logic. In my actual production code, all simplifications I could think of have been tested already. That includes reused terms.

Comment: i should have figured considering you said you put effort in. One last possibility I can think of - have you considered constructing sparse matrices (`Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> sparsesMat`) from each of your terms, summing them up and then using the dense matrix constructor that takes the sparse matrix (` denseMat = MatrixXd(sparseMat)`)?

Comment: No, I haven't used sparse matrices at all yet, because so far there hasn't really been an obvious use case for them in my code. Could you go into a bit more detail? It sounds interesting :)

Comment: can't say much - a while ago I was digging into it but then settled on using tensors instead. in short - you can construct a sparse C_ij as f(i,j). I don't recall the syntax but I think it is in the docs. The relevant bit is that there is a dense matrix contsructor from the sparse matrix.

naively I am thinking maybe you can do the if terms in a sparse environment and the other terms in a dense environment, and then combine them